# Conditional filling NA rows with comparing non-NA labeled rows

Tags: r, function, dplyr, difference

I want to fill NA rows based on checking the differences between *the closest* non-NA labeled rows.

For instance

```
data <- data.frame(sd_value=c(34,33,34,37,36,45),  
                   value=c(383,428,437,455,508,509),                   
                   label=c(c("bad",rep(NA,4),"unable")))

> data
  sd_value value  label
1       34   383    bad
2       33   428   <NA>
3       34   437   <NA>
4       37   455   <NA>
5       36   508   <NA>
6       45   509 unable
```

I want to evaluate how to change `NA` rows with checking the difference between `sd_value` and `value` those close to `bad` and `unable`rows.

if we want to get differences between the rows we can do;

```
library(dplyr)
data%>%
mutate(diff_val=c(0,diff(value)), diff_sd_val=c(0,diff(sd_value)))

  sd_value value  label diff_val diff_sd_val
1       34   383    bad        0           0
2       33   428   <NA>       45          -1
3       34   437   <NA>        9           1
4       37   455   <NA>       18           3
5       36   508   <NA>       53          -1
6       45   509 unable        1           9
```

The condition how I want to label the `NA` rows is

if the `diff_val<50` and `diff_sd_val<9` label them with the last `non-NA` label else use the first `non-NA` label after the last `NA` row.

So that the expected output would be

```
sd_value value  label diff_val diff_sd_val
    1       34   383    bad        0           0
    2       33   428    bad       45          -1
    3       34   437    bad        9           1
    4       37   455    bad       18           3
    5       36   508 unable    53          -1
    6       45   509 unable        1           9
```

The possible solution I cooked up so far:

```
custom_labelling <- function(x,y,label){

    diff_sd_val<-c(NA,diff(x))

    diff_val<-c(NA,diff(y))
    label <- NA
    for (i in 1:length(label)){

      if(is.na(label[i])&diff_sd_val<9&diff_val<50){

      label[i] <- label
      }
      else {

        label <- label[i]
      }
    }
    return(label)
  }
```

which gives

```
data%>%
  mutate(diff_val=c(0,diff(value)), diff_sd_val=c(0,diff(sd_value)))%>%
  mutate(custom_label=custom_labelling(sd_value,value,label))
```

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
>     Evaluation error: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed.
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In if (is.na(label[i]) & diff_sd_val < 9 & diff_val < 50) { :
>     the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to find `NA` and non-NA index and based on the condition select the closest label to it.

```
library(dplyr)

#Create a new dataframe with diff_val and diff_sd_val
data1 <- data%>% mutate(diff_val=c(0,diff(value)), diff_sd_val=c(0,diff(sd_value)))

#Get the NA indices
NA_inds <- which(is.na(data1$label))
#Get the non-NA indices
non_NA_inds <- setdiff(1:nrow(data1), NA_inds)

#For every NA index
for (i in NA_inds) {
   #Check the condition
   if(data1$diff_sd_val[i] < 9 & data1$diff_val[i] < 50) 
     #Get the last non-NA label
     data1$label[i] <- data1$label[non_NA_inds[which.max(i > non_NA_inds)]]
   else
     #Get the first non-NA label after last NA value
     data1$label[i] <- data1$label[non_NA_inds[i < non_NA_inds]]
}


data1
#  sd_value value  label diff_val diff_sd_val
#1       34   383    bad        0           0
#2       33   428    bad       45          -1
#3       34   437    bad        9           1
#4       37   455    bad       18           3
#5       36   508 unable       53          -1
#6       45   509 unable        1           9
```

You can remove `diff_val` and `diff_sd_val` columns later if not needed.

---

We can also create a function

```
custom_label <- function(label, diff_val, diff_sd_val) {
   NA_inds <- which(is.na(label))
   non_NA_inds <- setdiff(1:length(label), NA_inds)
   new_label = label

   for (i in NA_inds) {
     if(diff_sd_val[i] < 9 & diff_val[i] < 50) 
       new_label[i] <- label[non_NA_inds[which.max(i > non_NA_inds)]]
     else
       new_label[i] <- label[non_NA_inds[i < non_NA_inds]]
   }
  return(new_label)
 }
```

and then apply it

```
data%>% 
  mutate(diff_val = c(0, diff(value)), 
         diff_sd_val = c(0, diff(sd_value)), 
         new_label = custom_label(label, diff_val, diff_sd_val))


#  sd_value value  label diff_val diff_sd_val new_label
#1       34   383    bad        0           0       bad
#2       33   428   <NA>       45          -1       bad
#3       34   437   <NA>        9           1       bad
#4       37   455   <NA>       18           3       bad
#5       36   508   <NA>       53          -1    unable
#6       45   509 unable        1           9    unable
```

If we want to apply it by group we can add a `group_by` statement and it should work.

```
data%>% 
   group_by(group) %>%
   mutate(diff_val = c(0, diff(value)), 
          diff_sd_val = c(0, diff(sd_value)), 
          new_label = custom_label(label, diff_val, diff_sd_val))
```

Comment: Thanks for solution. OTH, I need to do this actually in grouped data. So could you tweak your solution a little bit? so that it could be used this way   `mutate(new_label=custom_label(value,sd_value,label))` ?

Comment: @Alexander Sure. I have updated the answer. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks Ronak for quick action. I guess I can add more condition inside the function if required in this sense. Thanks!